# Variable value not modified

Tags: javascript

Why does this code equal 23 and not 26?

```
var foo = parseInt("23",10);

foo + 3;
alert(foo);
```

Comment: Just imagine how terrible a feature this would be! `x = 2; y = x + 40; // x = ??` Well, `foo + 3` (not changing the variable `foo`) isn't any different than `x + 40` above (not changing the variable `x`).

Comment: Because that's not how JavaScript or even Math works.

Answer (score 4):

You must re-assign foo to hold the new value:

```
foo = foo + 3;
```

`foo + 3;` is a valid expression, and is not an error, but will simply "disappear" without effecting a change to `foo`.

An alternative is to use compound assignment:

```
foo += 3;
```

Answer (score -1):

if you use `foo=foo+3;` then your output will be 26.